# downloading files using wget into bucket of my VM at GCP causes disconnection

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a VM on GCP and when I try to download a file into the bucket using `wget` I get the following error (**Transport endpoint is not connected**) after the download is finished. Then the file ends up as an empty file.

Why can't I download files using wget into the bucket? Firewall issues?

username@instance-2:~/my_bucket_2/ReferenceGenome$ wget http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg19/bigZips/ hg19.fa.gz --2021-03-27 05:56:45--  http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg19/bigZips/hg19.fa.gz Resolving hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu (hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu)... 128.114.119.163 Connecting to hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu (hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu)|128.114.119.163|:80... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: 948731419 (905M) [application/x-gzip] Saving to: ‘hg19.fa.gz.1’ hg19.fa.gz.1                 100%[=============================================>] 904.78M  18.6MB/s    in 50s      utime(hg19.fa.gz.1): **Transport endpoint is not connected** 2021-03-27 05:57:41 (18.2 MB/s) - ‘hg19.fa.gz.1’ saved [948731419/948731419]

Comment: What type of destination are you writing the file to? This appears to be a mounted file system error. Are you using a FUSE related product to mount remote storage systems? More details are required.

Comment: to mount I am using: gcsfuse my_bucket my_folder, where "my_bucket" is the bucket that I want to mount and"my_folder" is the folder on which the disk is mounted. I guess my problem is that using wget like this I am downloading it to the folder and not the bucket? How do I specify that the wget should get into the bucket? the address to the bucket is: "gs://my_bucket"

Comment: Your problem is not `wget`. Your problem is that `gcsfuse` has a problem.

Comment: I see. any idea how to troubleshoot the mounting?

Comment: Create a new question for `gcsfuse`.

Comment: But I don't know what to ask since I don't recognise the problem with gcsfuse...

Comment: You will need to figure out more details on the problem. Your question lacks any details where I could offer advice. The first step is to create a new question on https://serverfault.com/ with the tag `gcsfuse` as this is the wrong place for `gcsfuse` questions.

Answer (score 0):

The message `Transport endpoint is not connected` usually means there's some sort of trouble with the filesystem you're trying to use.

But if your credentials are in order and you were able to mount it then it shold work - I tried it with the file you provided and it was downloaded with no issues;

```
wb@cloudshell:~/wb$ wget http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg19/bigZips/hg19.fa.gz
--2021-03-29 14:37:39--  http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenpath/hg19/bigZips/hg19.fa.gz
Resolving hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu (hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu)... 128.114.119.163
Connecting to hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu (hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu)|128.114.119.163|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 948731419 (905M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘hg19.fa.gz’

hg19.fa.gz                         100%[=============================================================>] 904.78M  39.4MB/s    in 23s 

2021-03-29 14:38:09 (39.0 MB/s) - ‘hg19.fa.gz’ saved [948731419/948731419]

wb@cloudshell:~/wb$ df -h | grep wb
wb1                                1.0P     0  1.0P   0% /home/wb/wb
```

There may be several issues however preventing you from saving your file;

**1. Mount / OS permissions**
Check if you can write to the directory where you mounted your bucket. Just use `ls` command and if you see:

```
wb@gc1:~$ ls -l
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 wb wb 0 Mar 29 14:33 wb
```

then it's fine. But if you see `drwxr-xr-x 1 wb wb 0 Mar 29 14:33 wb` you won't be able to write to the directory.

**2. Service account permissions**

Check if the service account your VM instance is using has a [Storage Admin role](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#cloud-storage-roles).

**3. Check [API access scope](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes)** - it may also be the cause since it further limits what the VM can do (despite that the service account it uses may have Storage Object Admin role).